# Pending Publication Still 2 days On Google Play, Is that a problem?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I published an app on Google Play 2 month ago, publish process took just 4 hours. But now I want to publish 2 apps from different Google accounts but still "Pending publication"
1. app : 20 July 2019 18:30
2. app : 20 July 2019 21:00 (I tried change setting on Play Console today and the date change 22 July 2019)

I use same settings on Play console about 3 apps. Must I wait or can I do something?

Note: I can't add a screenshot on Stackoverflow.

> Edit:
>   Is that any problem? Could I did something wrong?
>
> Target audience and content
>
> Target age
>
> The target age group for your app is: 13-15, 16-17 and 18+
>
> Your app could unintentionally appeal to children
>
> The 'Not designed for children' label will be shown next to your app on Google Play. Learn more
>
> Designed for Families
>
> Your app is not enrolled in the Designed for Families programme

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue? And what time have you waited for changing status from Pending Publication?

Comment: I fix that, that's about "target age", I write Google Support and I changed my settings.

Comment: what do you mean with 'ss'?

Comment: it means "Screen Shot", I can't add image to my question. @knocte

Comment: what prevents you to add an image? and what prevents you to write the full word?

Comment: 'cause we are using that, and that's not about my question. So it doesn't matter. I fix the problem, I wrote already my solution. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix that, that's about "target age", I write Google Support and I changed my settings.

Comment: did you have to remove infants from the target age settings?